# Assigning a custom type to a user task in activiti

Tags: activiti

I have several process definitions in my application. All of them have a user task defined and this user task is of generic type, say a counting task wherein user has to count objects.

Individual process definitions are more specific, like for counting oranges, counting apples etc.So in individual BPMN files, I have attribute 'name' for user task which tells specifics, like name="countApples', name="countOranges".

But I also want to add an attribute to user task which tells its generic nature, ie counting in this case.

As I have already used name attribute, is there any other attribute for this purpose?

Comment: so you need to display counting in the taskName?

Comment: not in task name exactly, but similar attribute which then I can use in java code to identify that its a counting task.

Comment: have you tried `taskDefinitionKey`? you can modify it and use the `taskDefinitionKeyLike` query to search e.g. count-apples, count-oranges. the taskDefinitionKeyLike query for "count" will return both the tasks with apples and oranges.

Comment: As per the documentation for taskDefinitionKey/taskDefinitionKeyLike, id is the input needed. where id is as in <userTask id="xxx" ...>. In my case, id is already defined.

Comment: have you tried assigning your task a category - https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#restTasksGet?